# Mersenne primes and superperfect numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, perfect-numbers

*Definition: Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $n>0$. Then $n$ is said to be **superperfect** if $\sigma(\sigma(n)) = 2n$*. Where $\sigma$ is the sum of positive divisors arithmetic function. ($\sigma(n) = \sum_{d|n, d>0} d $)

I'm working on a problem which asks me to prove that if $2^p - 1$ is a Mersenne prime, then $2^{p-1}$ is superperfect.

So far all I've said in my proof is:

If $2^p - 1$ is a Mersenne prime, then p must be a prime number.

I'm not really sure how to proceed. Could someone nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you give a numerical example? I'm looking at $p=5$, and I can't see how $2^4$ is super-perfect.

Comment: $2^4 = 16$. If we plug it into $\sigma(\sigma(n))$ where $\sigma$ is the "sum of positive divisors function", we get $\sigma(\sigma(16)) = \sigma(31) = 32 = 2(2^4)$. Thus for n = $2^4$, n is superperfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe the following:

- $n\in\mathbb{N}\implies\sigma(2^{n-1})=\color{red}{2^n-1}$
- $2^n-1\in\mathbb{P}\implies\sigma(2^n-1)=1+(2^n-1)=\color{green}{2^n}$
- $2^n-1\in\mathbb{P}\implies\sigma(\sigma(\color{blue}{2^{n-1}}))=\sigma(\color{red}{2^n-1})=\color{green}{2^n}=2\cdot\color{blue}{2^{n-1}}$